# How to deserialize a JSON response from a RESTful webservice?

Tags: java, objective-c, json, rest, kvc

I'm trying to implement a simple command-line Java app that requests some resources from a RESTful webservice. Is there a way to automatically deserialize JSON responses into my model classes?

In Objective-C there is Key-Value-Coding that allows you to create objects, access variables and methods by their string representation. This can be used to automatically deserialize an XML or JSON document into objects and this is done by some third party libraries, like RestKit.

Is there something similar for Java? I know I could use a JSON parser to get a array and map representation of the document and then create my model objects myself, but I was wondering if this could be automated?

I spent the entire evening yesterday searching for libraries, tutorials and user guides. All of them were either explaining how to build a RESTful webservice, or if it was a client app, all they ever did is download some JSON and print it to system out.

Comment: Here's a sample about deserializing a JSON string using Jackson: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/. You could automate it if you're using another frameworks like Spring or Mule (or another that can do it for you *automatically*). Otherwise, you should explain more about your exact problem.

Comment: Another popular one is [GSON](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) and there are [many more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library)

Comment: A lot of Java folks don't even know how to deal with JSON "in the raw" -- they only know these frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

With this, you can create a class that "matches" your json data structure, and Jackson will automatically instantiate and populate the class for you. Then you're already integrated with the rest of your Java app.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example, using XStream library: (http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html)

```
package com.thoughtworks.xstream.json.test;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver;

public class ReadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"product\":{\"name\":\"Banana\",\"id\":123"
            + ",\"price\":23.0}}";

        XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
        xstream.alias("product", Product.class);
        Product product = (Product)xstream.fromXML(json);
        System.out.println(product.getName());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), It is Google's Library for Marshaling/UnMarshaling JSON to Java and Java to JSON.

You can also look for its tutorial at http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/